In set theory: What is the motivation for transitioning from first-order language to plural logic language?
I am reading Burgess's paper titled "Plural Logic and Set Theory." In this work, the motivation for transitioning the language of set theory from first-order logic to plural logic is based on the fact that when there is a formula describing a set with infinite objects, existential generalization over this condition cannot be expressed in first-order logic.
I still do not fully understand whether this reason provides sufficient motivation for switching the language to plural logic. If the reason is simply that expressions regarding infinite objects cannot be represented in first-order language, this seems to implicitly presuppose a constructivist perspective.
More seriously, I do not clearly understand the distinction between plural language and second-order language. What is the difference between plural quantifiers and second-order quantifiers? If plural quantifiers only include plural forms of individuals, I am not exactly sure how the plural forms of individuals and second-order variables are distinguished.
Is there perhaps a paper or book that thoroughly addresses the motivation for transitioning set theory in first-order language to plural forms? Alternatively, I would appreciate it if you could explain what constitutes sufficient motivation for this transition.

Book: Salvatore Florio & Oystein Linnebo, The Many and the One: A Philosophical Study of Plural Logic (Oxford University Press, 2021) as well as Alex Oliver & Timothy Smiley, Plural Logic (Oxford UP, 2013)

Plural quantifiers still belong to a first order language, and if they have built-in infinite existential import, then it does express your pointed case while classical (finite) quantifier cannot express. Classical FOL has known expressive limitations such as inability to express the existence of infinite entities, while another famous way out is Hintikka's famous first order Independence-friendly logic inspired by game semantics of logic...

And see Plural Quantification for an introduction to the motivation of PQ: "we have good reason to admit among our primitive logical notions also the plural quantifiers ∀xx and ∃xx (for any things xx and there are some things xx)" and the application to Set Theory.
